# How can I delete everything from X to Y in a text document?

Tags: script, notepad++, text-editing, editing, sublime-text

Lets say, given a text document with the content:

```
zeep XXX fleem flerb 

floot flop 
YYY zoop 

yim XXX abc def 

jpg gif 
YYY yam
```

i want to delete everything in between XXX and YYY so it looks like:

```
zeep XXXYYY zoop

yim XXXYYY yam
```

How can I do this with a single command?

I currently use sublime text 3 and notepad++ on windows 10 but this question is platform agnostic. I'll use anything that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I want to delete everything in between XXX and YYY

In notepad++

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `XXX.*?YYY`
- Set "Replace with" to `XXXYYY`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Enable ". matches newline"
- Click "Replace All"

[image]

**Before**:

```
zeep XXX fleem flerb 

floot flop 
YYY zoop 

yim XXX abc def 

jpg gif 
YYY yam
```

**After**:

```
zeep XXXYYY zoop 

yim XXXYYY yam
```

---

#### Further reading

- [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation ? | Notepad++ Community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)